# Vimeo iframe embed video's not playing on iPad's

Tags: ipad, iframe, embed, vimeo

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked, but i didn't find a working  solution.

We have website with a Vimeo video on it. But it doesn't work on iPad. 
I tested in windows firefox and in Google chrome. It worked fine there.

Following is embed iframe code which I am using right now.

```
<iframe id="vimeo-video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/198187623?autoplay=1&amp;color=ffffff&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
```

What is causing this ? Need Guidance.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `&#10;` following the video id in the iframe src is interfering with the Player being rendered. When that part of the uri is removed, the player works as expected.

Tested with an iPad Mini 2 w/ iOS 10.2